# Point in opengis Polygon

Tags: java, point-in-polygon, opengis

I have a given opengis-Polygon (org.opengis.geometry.coordinate.Polygon) and I need a method to determine whether a given point is within the area that that Polygon spans up. Up until now I used: `polygon.getBoundary().getMbRegion().contains(point)`. That works fine as long as the polygon is not "tilted" because it checks the max and min latitudes and longitudes and compares them to the point's coordinates. `polygon.getSurface()` which I would use intuitively returns null for me and `polygon.getBoundary()` otherwise just gives me access to the points on the boundary of the polygon. Another thing I thought of trying was implementing the [Ray casting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm). But to implement that I did not yet find the possibility to create rays in opengis/GeoTools.

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright for anyone who stumbles upon this problem again, I solved the issue by implementing the algorithm proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922778/3709553).